# Load multiple objects into list in firebase

Tags: binding, firebase, angularfire

I have a list of id referencing data in a firebase database. Is there a way to query firebase for these id's together and get at list that will be synchronized like a normal firebase list.

I'm currently using $bind on my $firebase for my other lists. Is it possible to create list that functions the same where I can cherry pick the elements at load.

```
var ids = ['-JFbfOzDh22OC8EXpruD','-JFbfHMjnFKOWtRQCBUy']; //I want to load these ids
var dataRef = new Firebase("http::<...>/items");
$scope.items = $firebase(dataRef);
$scope.items.$bind($scope, "bounditems");
```

Comment: Sorry to be dense; isn't $scope.items already a list? Maybe explaining the use case (what you want to use this for) would help.